# Socket rooms amount

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Assuming we've got an application with lots of posts which can be single viewed. The single view contains the comments to the post.

I want to make the comment system in real time (so new comments are shown instantly without refreshing) with sockets, but I'm not totally sure how to do that:

1. by viewing a post the user subscribes to a room for the specific post (`post_{id}`). New comments are broadcast to this room.
2. broadcasting a `new_comment` event to all sockets and evaluate it client-side (e.g. having a `post_id`)

The problem I see with the first idea:

- after viewing multiple posts we subscribe to a lot of rooms. I don't know if this is a problem, but it feels a bit weird. I can't unsubscribe from rooms due to tabs.

The problem I see with the second idea:

- It's not possible anymore to maintain permissions. For example if you can't see a specific post, you'd still get the `new_comment` event for it and therefor can read the comments without a serious amount of work (developer console > listen for the event and `console.log` its data > win).

Or is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

It should work perfectly fine for each page that views a single view of a post (with comments), to be put in a room that is specific to that post.  It is your server adding a connection to the room so it can make sure and do that only for a user that has the ability to view that post.

Then, when a new comment arrives for a post, you just broadcast to the associated room and only those who are already viewing that post will get the message.

When a web page is navigated away from or a tab is closed, any webSocket connection that page has open is automatically closed and when it is closed, socket.io will automatically remove it from any rooms that it is in so you don't have to worry about that level of cleanup.

I'd suggest that you derive a room name from the post ID in order to name the room.

> The problem I see with the first idea:
>
> after viewing multiple posts we subscribe to a lot of rooms. I don't
>   know if this is a problem, but it feels a bit weird. I can't
>   unsubscribe from rooms due to tabs.

This shouldn't be a problem.  Each tag would only be viewing a single post and thus only be subscribed to comment notifications for one post.  When the tab is navigated away from or closed, the socket.io connection will be automatically closed and removed from any rooms it is in.

Comment: But since I'm never refreshing the page how to unsubscribe correctly? I do know that I'm _not_ automatically disconnected from the rooms when leaving the post. I'm using Angular on client and a controller (responsible for viewing a single post) sends a subscribe request to the server. After that I'm never disconnected until the page is refreshed or sth similar.

Comment: @nehalist - If you're using a single page app (that changes which post it is viewing without loading a new page), then you can just send your server a message on the socket.io connection asking it to unsubscribe you from the previous posting and it can then remove your socket from that room.  You will presumably also have to ask it to subscribe you to the new posting.

Comment: Okay, but here's the problem again with tabs: opening a new post while already viewing a post would cause to unsubscribe from the previous post - which is bad, since it's still open.

Comment: @nehalist - I don't understand what the problem is.  You are in total control of which messages you're still subscribed to.  Just have the client tell the server when to subscribe to a post and when to unsubscribe.  Your client code is in total control.  If you're opening more than one post in the same browser window, then subscribe to comment notifications for more than one post.  If you're getting comment notifications on the same socket for more than one post, then you will need to include the post ID when you send the comment so the client code knows which post the comment belongs to.

Comment: @nehalist - Opening a new tab in the browser (an actual new browser window) won't do anything to the other tab - it should just keep going on getting its notifications.  If you're causing this problem on your server, then stop doing that.  Each new socket.io connection should be treated on its own.  Something that happens on one should not affect any other connection.

Comment: I think I stil don't get it. Since I've got a SPA how to know when to unsubscribe? Opening multiple posts means that I have to subscribe to multiple rooms simultaneously. Due to the nature of SPA I'm not really closing the connection at any point - which means I need to unsubscribe manually. But how to know when to do that? What if I have the same post opened multiple times?

Comment: @nehalist - Your client code just needs to know what is and isn't being displayed and register for notifications on those.  If you get rid of displaying a post, then unregister for that one.  If a new post is opened, then register for that one.  Why is this so difficult to do?  Your client code just needs to know what is and isn't being displayed so it can keep the subscriptions up-to-date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116290/discussion-between-nehalist-and-jfriend00).